# Error in itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter for images with 1 row and N columns

Tags: c++, vector, itk

I am new to both C++ and ITK (and a newbie to stackoverflow as well). I have been fiddling with test code for learning purposes. The following is a simple piece of code to read in a grayscale image, threshold it to get a binary image, and get a label map out of it. I use MS VS2010 and ITK v4.5.1.

```
typedef itk::Image< unsigned char, 2 >  ScalarImageType;

typedef itk::ImageFileWriter< ScalarImageType > WriterType;
typedef itk::ImageFileReader< ScalarImageType > ReaderType;

typedef itk::OtsuThresholdImageFilter< ScalarImageType, ScalarImageType > OtsuThresholdImageFilterType;
typedef itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter< ScalarImageType > BinaryImageToLabelMapFilterType;

// read a grayscale image
ReaderType::Pointer reader = ReaderType::New();
reader->SetFileName("test_grey.jpg");
try
{
    reader->Update();
}
catch( itk::ExceptionObject &err )
{
    std::cerr << "ExceptionObject caught !" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << err << std::endl;
    return(FALSE);
}

// threshold the grayscale image
OtsuThresholdImageFilterType::Pointer otsuThresImgFilter = OtsuThresholdImageFilterType::New();
otsuThresImgFilter->SetInput(reader->GetOutput());
otsuThresImgFilter->SetInsideValue(255);
otsuThresImgFilter->SetOutsideValue(0);
try
{
    otsuThresImgFilter->Update();
}
catch( itk::ExceptionObject &err )
{
    std::cerr << "ExceptionObject caught !" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << err << std::endl;
    return(FALSE);
}

// get a label map from the binary image
BinaryImageToLabelMapFilterType::Pointer binarytoLabelmapFilter = BinaryImageToLabelMapFilterType::New();
binarytoLabelmapFilter->SetInput(otsuThresImgFilter->GetOutput());
try
{
    binarytoLabelmapFilter->Update();
}
catch( itk::ExceptionObject &err )
{
    std::cerr << "ExceptionObject caught !" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << err << std::endl;
    return(FALSE);
}
```

This works fine for all images, except those which have only 1 row and N columns (interestingly, 1 x 1 images go through fine).

So, for 1 x N images, the program crashes in release mode. In debug mode, I get the "vector subscript out of range" error. Stepping through the code, I found that the crash happens on the line **`binarytoLabelmapFilter->Update();`** of my code.

Call stack:

```
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgBreak()  Line 85   C
msvcr100d.dll!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType, const wchar_t * szFile, int nLine, const wchar_t * szModule, const wchar_t * szFormat, char * arglist)  Line 502    C
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType, const wchar_t * szFile, int nLine, const wchar_t * szModule, const wchar_t * szFormat, char * arglist)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes   C++
msvcr100d.dll!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType, const wchar_t * szFile, int nLine, const wchar_t * szModule, const wchar_t * szFormat, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes   C++
msvcp100d.dll!std::_Debug_message(const wchar_t * message, const wchar_t * file, unsigned int line)  Line 13 + 0x16 bytes   C++
HelloWorld.exe!std::vector<std::vector<itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter<itk::Image<unsigned char,2>,itk::LabelMap<itk::LabelObject<unsigned long,2> > >::runLength,std::allocator<itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter<itk::Image<unsigned char,2>,itk::LabelMap<itk::LabelObject<unsigned long,2> > >::runLength> >,std::allocator<std::vector<itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter<itk::Image<unsigned char,2>,itk::LabelMap<itk::LabelObject<unsigned long,2> > >::runLength,std::allocator<itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter<itk::Image<unsigned char,2>,itk::LabelMap<itk::LabelObject<unsigned long,2> > >::runLength> > > >::operator[](unsigned int _Pos)  Line 932 + 0x17 bytes C++
HelloWorld.exe!itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter<itk::Image<unsigned char,2>,itk::LabelMap<itk::LabelObject<unsigned long,2> > >::ThreadedGenerateData(const itk::ImageRegion<2> & outputRegionForThread, unsigned int threadId)  Line 190 + 0x1c bytes  C++
HelloWorld.exe!itk::ImageSource<itk::LabelMap<itk::LabelObject<unsigned long,2> > >::ThreaderCallback(void * arg)  Line 295 + 0x25 bytes    C++
HelloWorld.exe!itk::MultiThreader::SingleMethodProxy(void * arg)  Line 375 + 0xe bytes  C++
msvcr100d.dll!_callthreadstartex()  Line 314 + 0xf bytes    C
msvcr100d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd)  Line 297  C
kernel32.dll!773f338a()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]  
ntdll.dll!77a49f72()    
ntdll.dll!77a49f45()
```

Any idea what's going on? Any tips on how to investigate further? Being a novice, I am not sure if it is an issue in ITK that I should raise as a bug or if it is due to something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to relate to the number of threads used by **BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter**.
The error disappears if I set the number of threads to 1, by adding the line

```
binarytoLabelmapFilter->SetNumberofThreads(1);
```

before updating the filter.

It seems to be a bug in ITK. Discussion thread in the ITK mailing list - http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/community/2014-July/003110.html